# How is the Apple FairPlay Server Playback Context (SPC) message generated?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, ios, drm, safari

I'm researching encryption tools that use OS-verified hardware such as a TPM or Secure Element.

Given that [FairPlay only works on iOS and certain Mac hardware](https://developer.apple.com/streaming/fps/), I suspect there is some interaction between the FairPlay AV Foundation and the Secure Element

**Question**

- When the SPC is given to the server, what cryptographically verifiable information is disclosed from the client to the server?
- Does the SPC message interact with the Secure Element?  In what ways (symmetric, asymmetric, etc)?

Comment: Discovered that the HU element of the SPC tells the server a unique ID: https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/29631#29631